# How to post non-form data from Razor Page to Page Model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am just getting started on web programming (using Razor Pages) and am having a problem figuring out how to post data that is not directly entered on the form back to the server. I am hoping to do it without Ajax as I need to redirect after the data is processed.

Here is a piece of the form [.cshtml]

```
@page
@model TaiRoxWeb.Models.FilterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Filter";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Filter Criteria
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm" id="tblFilter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Line
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FilterTerms[0].DisplayFieldName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FilterTerms[0].DisplayOperation)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FilterTerms[0].DisplayValues)
                        </th>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="text-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnAddLine">Add...</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnClearAll">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" asp-page-handler="Cancel" asp-route-PageName="@Model.PageName">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-page-handler="Submit" asp-route-PageName="@Model.PageName" asp-route-FilterTerms="FilterTerms">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On page load existing data is appended to the table.
A modal popup is used to add/edit data, which updates the table.

This is the page handler for the Submit button.

```
public ActionResult OnPostSubmit([FromForm] List<SelectTerm> filter)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    return RedirectToPage(@"/" + PageName);
}
```

The model

```
public class SelectTerm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FieldName { get; set; } // select field's Name

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the display-friendly form of FieldName that is shown in the selection criteria grid.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Field")]
    public string DisplayFieldName { get; set; } // select field's DisplayName

    public SelectOperation Operation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the display-friendly form of Operation that is shown in the selection criteria grid.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Operation")]
    public string DisplayOperation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Values.
    /// This is a list of strings in order to support the "Is One Of" operation.
    /// All filter types except "Is One Of" use only the first item in the list.
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the display-friendly form of Values that is shown in the selection criteria grid.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Value(s)")]
    public string DisplayValues { get; set; }
}
```

The "display friendly" properties are displayed in the users language in the form's table. The non-display friendly (language-neutral) properties are needed back on the server for processing.

As selection/filter criteria are added/edited a javascript array [named FilterTerms] is maintained. It stores the complete for each row in the table.

How do I get the data back to the server when the Submit button is clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into @Html.HiddenFor?

Comment: Yes, but still stuck with requiring input fields on the form. One of the model properties is a list/array so the model binding gets a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get data back to the server is via a post. As a result, all data you want sent must have an associated input in the form, even if it's hidden.

The only other option is to utilize JS to build a custom post body and send it via AJAX. You can still *technically* redirect by change `location` in the AJAX success callback. However, it's better and more straight-forward to just use a traditional form post, unless you actually need to remain on the same page.

**UPDATE**

After giving your code a closer look, I think your issue might be that the data you're requiring is display-only stuff that should not actually be posted back in the first place. If that's the case, the solution is to rebuild your view model on post. If there's some property(ies) that are only for display, then those values should be set every time by whatever code set them in the first place. I'd need to see more of your code to give you more specific guidance, there, though.

Comment: Agree with your comment re Ajax. I have played with separating the display only from required data, but still stuck with needing input fields on the form.  I was hoping that there was a way to specify explicitly what data to send back when the submit button was clicked.

Comment: Inputs are that "way to specify explicitly what data to send back when the submit button was clicked", However, you should only ever post data that a user is allowed to change. Everything else should come from the server always. Yes, that may mean doing database queries and such again. No, that's not an issue.

Comment: I'll give this approach a try. My post back data contains a list of lists so was fearful that the standard model binding would not be sufficient. Thanks Chris.

Comment: By separating the display only data from the data needed in the post back and then creating hidden input fields on the form for the post back data I was able to get the model binding to work. Thanks again Chris..